# Need SDK to query google advanced search for search counts

Tags: search-engine

I am looking for an SDK or a script for submitting google advanced searches to the google website. (Google Search API does not give the same amount of entries than the normal google search)

I am interested in the number of results only. I would like to use the data_range feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found nothing, did it myself:

https://github.com/froth/gasc